VBA Excel Autofilter Using Array For Multiple Values Fails
Filter will not include 49 along with AA, BB, and CC.
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Array("AA", "BB", "CC")
CrtTrackWS.Range("A1", "AQ" & last_rowCrt).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myArrary, _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

This provides the expected results of filtering rows with AA, BB, and CC
Change myArray to this: myArray = Array("*49*", "AA", "BB", "CC")
The filter will not include 49.
Changing myArray to this: myArray = Array("*49*", "AA")
The filter will include 49 and AA.
How do I get filter to included 49, AA, BB, and CC?

Criteria1:=myArrary ?   When using wildcards you're limited to two values in the array I think.

Possibly helpful Filter out multiple criteria using Excel VBA ?
